# sending mail with attachments in laravel 5.4 through mailgun

Tags: php, laravel, email, mailgun

I'm having problems sending attachments in mail with mailgun.

When I go to logs in mailgun, the mail sent shows :

```
      "attachments": [],
```

Here's my code :

```
      $location = Storage::get('attachments/'.$this-attachments->file_name);
      return $this->markdown('emails.create',["desc" => $this->mail->description])
           ->subject($this->mail->subject)
           ->attach($location);
```

I got raw encoded codes when I return the $location so i tried doing with public_path() but the result was same( "attachments":[], <- in mailgun logs ).

Am i doing it wrong? How do i get the attachment in the mail? The mail is going through but not with attachments.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please check dd($location);  and which output get you

Comment: on public_path() i get the path i.e C:drive and i get raw encoded codes if i use Storage::get().

Comment: So what is the output of $location because you get attachment is null right?

Comment: ->attach()  should have the path to file right? or should it have the file itself? I tried both . Everything's fine on my part so i thought there might be other way to send the attachments using mailgun. $location gives me the path to my file which is inside C: drive .

Comment: Ok i get it your point

Comment: Please follow this link(http://www.expertphp.in/article/how-to-send-e-mail-using-laravel-5-with-example) hope this work for you

Answer (score 1):

Try below code with [storage_path()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-storage-path):

```
$location = storage_path('attachments/'.$this-attachments->file_name);

return $this->markdown('emails.create',["desc" => $this->mail->description])
->subject($this->mail->subject)
->attach($location);
```

Comment: Tried doing it but doesn't work. So I moved from using markdown to normal view method and it started working. -_-  it's really annoying, idk what's wrong with markdown's. Anyway thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You wrote

```
$location = Storage::get('attachments/' . $this-attachments->file_name);
```

But it should be

```
$location = Storage::get('attachments/' . $this->attachments->file_name);
```

You forgot the `>` in `$this->`